# Implementing AutoCorrect/Spellcheck Functionality in Sencha Touch

Tags: ios, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

We want to implement Autocorrect/Spellcheck functionality in sencha touch textareafield . AutoCorrect/Spellcheck property is working in safari browser , but it is not working in iOS UIWebview . Please help me out to achieve this.

Thanks
Saranya

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth (I know this is an old post), I was able to get the 'spellcheck' attribute set, but was not able to get it to work on a native PhoneGap app:

```
                        {
                            xtype: 'textareafield',
                            placeHolder: 'What\'s on your mind?',
                            autoComplete: true,
                            autoCorrect: true,
                            listeners: {
                                painted: function(){
                                    this.element.query('textarea')[0].setAttribute('spellcheck','true');
                                }
                            }
                        }
```